# VLookup - Visual Basic - how to set a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a `Vlookup` formula set in cell `D5` that checks some data in cell `E5`, does the `Vlookup` below, and returns the result:

```
=VLOOKUP(E5,StockCodesBBG!A:J,2,FALSE)
```

What I would like to do is to have a way of automatically counting the number of rows I have populated from `E5` down, and then running the `Vlookup` formula for each of those corresponding cells.

For example, say I have data in `E5,E6,E7`, I would like the formula to apply itself into `D5,D6,D7`.

I can just `Autofill` this down by copying the formula, but it leaves a load of messy `#N/A` values where there is nothing in the `E` column to reference. How do I avoid the in cell error messages?

Comment: There is no need for VBA here :)

Comment: `A:J` is a bit over the top and may impact performance: best to narrow the lookup to just the cells you require.

Answer (score 3):

You can AutoFill it but at the same time handle the `#N/A` so that you do not see those obnoxious values :)

If using **xl2003**, use this

`=if(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(E5,StockCodesBBG!A:J,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(E5,StockCodesBBG!A:J,2,FALSE))`

or

`=if(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E5,StockCodesBBG!A:J,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(E5,StockCodesBBG!A:J,2,FALSE))`

If using **xl2007+**, use this

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E5,StockCodesBBG!A:J,2,FALSE),"")`

Check the Excel help on `ISERROR`,`ISNA`,`IFERROR`

Comment: Hiya, Thanks for the reply - that does indeed hide the #N/A values, but what i didn't mention is that after these values are returned there is another unrelated formula to automatically upload the returned results into another application (I didn't write this bit !). So i can't really have any false values returned in the column D else the upload fails !

Comment: Then don't use the error handling, let the cells show you `#N/A`. You can then simply copy paste the entire column as values and then do a find and replace to remove `#N/A`?

Comment: Do you remove the row if the value is false? If you sub something else in why not put that value in the `True` part of the `IF(ISNA)` statement?

Comment: Hiya - i would do, unfortunately this sheet is going over to a load of business users who won't be able to work out how to do that simple thing ! That's the reasin i was looking for the Vlookup range function. Thanks for your suggestions though !

Comment: @DHughes: Umm, What do you mean by False values? The formula is returning a blank. If you want, you can replace `""` by `0` so that if there is an error, it shows `0` there.

Comment: +1 crickey....I'm still using `IF(ISNA(...` in 2010; didn't know about `IFERROR`; nice new function

Comment: @SiddharthRout `A:J` seems a bit overkill?

Comment: @whytheq: Yup. You are right but I was not concentrating on that :). You might want to suggest OP in a comment below the question?